# postsharp aspect async method at call time

Tags: c#, postsharp

when we call an async method A, we can await directly (the code will be executed in sequence), or await later (some code after inner await will be executed asynchronous in a new task).

now, I'm using postsharp aspect[OnMethodBoundaryAspect] to method A, i want to inject different code when await directly or later, how can i know it?

```cs
public class Program
{
    [PostsharpAttr]
    public async Task<int> B()
    {
        var value = await A();
        // [operation B] this opeation will execute after operation A
        return value;
    }

    [PostsharpAttr]
    public async Task<int> C()
    {
        var valueT = A();
        // [operation C] this operation may parallel execute with operation A
        var value = await valueT;
        return value;
    }

    [PostsharpAttr]
    public async Task<int> A()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        // [operation A]
        return 1;
    }
}
public class PostsharpAttrAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        bool awaitDirectly = false;
        var asyncAttr = args.Method.GetCustomAttributes<AsyncStateMachineAttribute>();
        if (asyncAttr != null)
        {// is async method
            if (awaitDirectly)
            {
                // if await directly
            }
            else
            {
                // if await later
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

await async method will generate two lines IL code, these two lines of code will be together if await method directly.

```
async Task<int> B()
{
    var value = await A();
    var d = D();
    return value + d;
}

async Task<int> C()
{
    var valueT = A();
    var d = D();
    var value = await valueT;
    return value + d;
}
```

part of the method B IL code:

```
L_0010: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> PostsharpTest.Temp::A()
L_0015: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<!0> [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32>::GetAwaiter()
```

part of the method C IL code:

```
L_0010: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> PostsharpTest.Temp::A()
L_0015: ldarg.0 
L_0016: ldarg.0 
L_0017: ldfld class PostsharpTest.Temp PostsharpTest.Temp/<C>d__2::<>4__this
L_001c: callvirt instance int32 PostsharpTest.Temp::D()
L_0021: stfld int32 PostsharpTest.Temp/<C>d__2::<d>5__1
L_0026: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<!0> [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32>::GetAwaiter()
```

if await directly, task.GetAwaiter just below async method call.
so i think the postsharp can find out asyns method call and determine whether it is directly await at compile time, then inject some code(set postsharp attribute property) before call the method. 
if postsharp can do this, in `OnMethodBoundaryAspect.OnEntry` or `MethodInterceptionAspect.Invoke` will know this call is await directly or later.

Comment: Can you please describe any benefit it could bring? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to inject different code when await directly or later, how can i know it?

You cannot know this. You're asking the code to see into the future.

Think about it this way: when an `async` method is invoked, it must (synchronously) return a `Task`. There is no way for that method to be notified when that task is awaited.

Or step into the synchronous world for a minute. Consider a method that returns an integer. Your question would then become "I want to inject different code when that integer is displayed to the `Console`, than when that integer is displayed in a `TextBox`". It's simply not possible to know what the calling code will do with your return value *in the future*.

Now, you *could* return something quite different (not with an Aspect, but bear with me). You could return an integer-like object that observes its calling code when cast to an integer and has a different result if it's going to the `Console`. Similarly, you could return a custom awaitable from an `async` method that takes some special action when it's actually awaited. But these approaches are hacky and weird.

It's better to take a step back, think about *what problem you're actually trying to solve*, and find a more reasonable solution.

Comment: await async method will generate tow lines IL code. these two lines of code will be together if await method directly. postsharp povide compile time initialize, is possible check the method body at compile time, find out async method call and tell the  method is await directly or not.

Comment: That approach would be even more hacky, dependent on specific compiler output that may change in the future or based on different optimization settings or other code in the calling method. I recommend taking a step back, thinking about *what problem you're actually trying to solve*, and finding a more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to realize the meaning of awaiting the result.

If you start an async method you create a task right away. That potentially means it gets executed right away. So any method boundary (entry) code will already have been executed.

That said you could write code like this.

```
public class PostsharpAttrAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
      bool awaitDirectly = false;

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {

       var asyncAttr = args.Method.GetCustomAttributes<AsyncStateMachineAttribute>();
       if (asyncAttr != null)
       {// is async method
            if (awaitDirectly)
            {
                base.OnInvoke();
                var task = (Task)args.ReturnValue;
                task.Wait()
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnInvoke();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

You could use this to make your code synchronous (act like everything is awaited directly) by just setting awaitDirectly to true in the attribute, regardless how it's actually called.

An async method returns a task. That task might execute at any time but this way you could force waiting for it.

Note: In c# there are some deadlock options if you mix task & async/await. ConfigureAwait(false) is a way to around this usually but i'm not sure how you would apply that with postsharp. I hope this give you at least some ideas how to experiment & continue

Update: even though there is a difference in IL, i'm not sure this is reliable enough that you can do quite what you want (optimalizations might cause different result in different situations)

Also postsharp design is based on around the idea that you change the way things are called. (For example always make the results cached).

If the difference is in how you are calling it, why not just wrap it in a function.

Comment: as you say, this way will force waiting for the result, i won't change code execute order. my problem is difficult to solve at runtime, but it will be easier at compile time. await async method will generate tow lines IL code. these two lines of code will be together if await method directly. so i think postsharp can recognize the invocation way of async method at compile time, and set the invocation way to postsharp attribute property by static inject.

Comment: i think you are missing the idea of AOP though. maybe postsharp could detect it. but it probably won't since it would go against the design. AOP/Postsharp deal with cross cutting concerns. what you are trying to do feels not to fit in. (In general functions should never look at how they are called).
Maybe you could expand on why you are trying to do this so we might suggest some good alternatives.